# Benefits of Rails without ActiveRecord, Grails without GORM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hibernate, activerecord, grails, grails-orm

We have several large web applications written in a variety of versions of Struts and Tapestry; we're not particularly happy with any of those web app frameworks and we're looking to pick a new one for development of future applications.

The kicker is that we still want the new stuff to leverage our existing data, which is basically SOAP web services backed by Hibernate -- we don't want to rewrite any of that.

My limited experience with Rails suggests that a lot of the benefit comes from the integration of ActiveRecord, and I'm guessing that Grails/GORM is a similar situation. I'm wondering, what are the other major benefits of Rails and Rails-like frameworks? What are the reasons you would choose a Rails-like framework if you weren't going to get to use its ORM system, and what are the reasons you wouldn't?

Comment: For future readers: Nine years later, with several years of Rails experience, I'd say the biggest benefits are routing (what gets called when what URL is hit) and (M)VC auto-wiring (e.g. looking up views based on controller class and method names). You can also take advantage of some ActiveRecord-like behavior (e.g. validation) by using ActiveModel, even without the ORM.

Answer (score 1):

I can’t speak for Rails but have done some Grails development as well as standard Spring/Hibernate Java development. Without GORM Grails main advantage is its simplicity. You can still make use of the configuration by convention to use views and controllers by creating classes and GSP pages under the standard folders. This eliminates the need to write Spring XML files or use annotations on your classes to declare them as a controller or view. Groovy which Grails uses also has some nice features such as Closures and dynamic typing. It’s also nice to create a class in Groovy and have variables be public by default with getters and setters added at runtime, saving a lot of boilerplate code. Grails can also make use of an existing Hibernate domain model. If your web application will be able to directly access the Database using your existing Hibernate domain model instead of going through a web service front end take a look at [this link](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/08/26/reuse-your-hibernatejpa-domain-model-with-grails/) for info on integrating your existing domain model with Grails.